# Why does the Digital Goods API's getService method reject with clientAppUnavailable in my TWA?

Tags: trusted-web-activity

We have [a TWA/PWA](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ntslive.ntsradio) in the Play store. We want to start selling Play subscriptions through our app.

We followed the Chrome Developer [guides](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/trusted-web-activity/play-billing/) to implementing the necessary steps in the Android project and the PWA. We also checked our code against the Android Browser Helper [demo](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/tree/main/demos/twa-play-billing) and the code generated by the latest Bubblewrap version. (We did not use Bubblewrap to generate our project, however.) As far as we can see, our functionality is equivalent. We tried bundling the same versions of the `androidbrowserhelper:androidbrowserhelper` and `androidbrowserhelper:billing` dependencies as Bubblewrap. We also tried downgrading to those used in TWA Play Billing Demo.

With these prerequisites (hopefully) in place in the Android wrapper, we configured a subscription product (with a base plan) in the Play console.

Now we are trying to test fetching product details using the Digitial Goods API, following the examples linked above.
We can successfully detect the availability of the API in our context. We also find the call to `window.getDigitalGoodsService('https://play.google.com/billing')` successfully resolves.
We await the service object before calling `service.getDetails([ 'our_sku' ])`, but this call rejects with an error `clientAppUnavailable`.

We cannot find any clarification related to this error, either in resources about Android Browser Helper nor the (Android) Google Play Billing Library.

The following snippets illustrate the relevant code (IMO) in our codebases.

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation 'com.google.androidbrowserhelper:androidbrowserhelper:2.4.0'

    implementation 'com.google.androidbrowserhelper:billing:1.0.0-alpha09'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-android:6.1.2'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service
            android:name=".DigitalGoodsDelegationService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.TRUSTED_WEB_ACTIVITY_SERVICE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

DigitalGoodsDelegationService.java

```
import com.google.androidbrowserhelper.playbilling.digitalgoods.DigitalGoodsRequestHandler;
import com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.DelegationService;

public class DigitalGoodsDelegationService extends DelegationService{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerExtraCommandHandler(new DigitalGoodsRequestHandler(getApplicationContext()));
    }
}
```

PWA

```
const SERVICE_ID = 'https://play.google.com/billing';

window.getDigitalGoodsService(SERVICE_ID)
    .then((service) => {
        if (!service) throw new Error(ERROR_MESSAGES.noPlayBilling);

        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('Got service');
        return service.getDetails(SKUS);
    })
    .then(products => {
        if (!products || !products.length) {
            throw new Error(ERROR_MESSAGES.noProducts);
        }

        ...
    })
    .catch(err => {
        ...
    });
```

Comment: Hi. Did you ever have solved this? Currently trying the same and it's the same problem for me. Functions are registered properly in the TWA, but calling any service function will cause the rejection.

Comment: Hi Brian, see my answer below...

Comment: Ah ok, i see that it was you. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. Well, then i must continue my search for a solution. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We resolved the error by compiling against an upgraded version of the Android API. (Before, `compileSdkVersion` was set to `30` in our module-level `build.gradle`. We upgraded this to `31`.)